# view.frame is not set when IBDesignable loads xib

Tags: swift, uiview, interface-builder, ibdesignable

I have a simple `UIView` subclass that I have made `@IBDesignable`.
I overloaded `init frame` and `init coder`. My code loads the view description from a `.xib` file.
After the `.xib` file has been loaded I try to set:

```
view.clipsToBounds = true
view.layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.height / 2
```

to get a "rectangle with circular sides".

The problem is that `frame.size.height = 0` at that time (after `.xib` is loaded and my custom view drawn for the first time by Interface Builder).

Is there a workaround?

Here it is my code:

```
@IBDesignable
class CustomUIVIew: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        xibSetup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        xibSetup()
    }

    private var view: UIView!
    private let nibName = "CustomUIView"

    private func xibSetup() {

        view = loadViewFromNib()
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight]
        addSubview(view)
        setupView()
    }

    private func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {

        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

        return view
    }

    private func setupView() {

        view.clipsToBounds = true
        view.layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.height / 2
    }
}
```

Thank you, Luca-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move any size related adjustments into `layoutSubviews`. This way, not only will it be rendered correctly in IB, but also on device, if the size of the window changes, the `cornerRadius` will be adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

`prepareForInterfaceBuilder` did the job

```
override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    view.clipsToBounds = true
    view.layer.cornerRadius = bounds.height / 2
}
```